# Calling exe file in matlab with a user-dependent input

Tags: matlab

I have a .exe file and want to run it through Matlab. I know that I should use `!myfile.exe` or `system` and/or `evalc`. However, after running the .exe file, it asks for input: Please enter the name of input file.

So, the question is that how should I declare the name of the input in my .m file?

Comment: I think we need more information for a definite answer.  But if it is the `.exe` asking for a file name, you should be able to pass it as a parameter via the system call: `!myfile.exe filename` or (if you need the current file name) `system(['myfile.exe ',mfilename('fullpath')])`.

Comment: The problem is that the exe file does not have any default input file and this file should be typed ! So, I really don't know that how I should enter the name of the input file after running the exe file.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "should be typed !" as the only difference, in my experience, is that the bang shell escape creates a literal line of system input while `system` allows for dynamic string input.  That said, if the `.exe` doesn't accept the filename as a direct input, you'll have to manually enter the filename it needs via the Matlab command window I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Yes :), it works. How can I remove some of the comments that execute after running the .exe file?

Comment: In this case, assuming you needed to enter the filename directly, you either need to deal with the comments, or have the system spawn a shell by appending a `&` for the end of the system call; then enter the filename in that shell and all comments will be restricted to the instance.

Comment: Actually I don't want to see the shell window :)

Comment: Then I'd say your options are limited.  Or you could look at the answer provided already.  Since I don't know Java, I can't comment on it.

Comment: Thank you anyway for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try the following scheme using the `java.awt.Robot` class.

```
r = java.awt.Robot;
system([myfile.exe ' &']); % dont forget to use the correct path if needed
pause(2) % allow some time for the computer to process
system([your_input_file_name ' &']);
r.keyPress (java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); % press "enter" key
r.keyRelease (java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); % release "enter" key
```

Another option is to use .net object if you are in windows by using `SendWait` and `SendKeys`, for example:

```
NET.addAssembly('System.Windows.Forms'); % import the .NET assembly
sendkey = @(strkey) System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(strkey) ; %useful function for the next lines:
%% now let's get started
system('myfile.exe &') ;   
pause(2);
sendkey('your_input_file_name')
sendkey('{ENTER}'); % press ENTER
```

credit to Luis Mendo and Hoki for telling me all about this